# Returning Google Search To Python

Tags: python, search, urllib2

I am trying to get the first 20 results from a Google search.
When I use `urllib2.urlopen()` it gives me an error and says I am forbidden.
I heard that it has something to do with faking you user agent string, but i have next to no urllib2 experience and would be very grateful if anyone could help.

Thanks,
giodamelio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably just use a library that does all the hard work.

[xGoogle](https://github.com/pkrumins/xgoogle) enables you to get the search results in a list

From the examples,

```
from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch
gs = GoogleSearch("quick and dirty")
gs.results_per_page = 50
results = gs.get_results()
```

Comment: In my case it always returns HTTP Error 403: Forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two ways - accessing Google's API directly, or using xGoogle package.

#### Gooogle's own API

Google's [JSON\Atom API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) requires you to get an account and a key. It is the standard and preferred way to get searches in an automated way, which means you won't be banned from their service. The request is quite simple (quoting Google's own example):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?
            key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures
```

You'll get a JSON response, which can  be easily processed using numerous Python packages.

#### xGoogle

The [xgoogle package](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/python-library-for-google-search/) is somewhat faster (see [Lakshman Prasad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363861/returning-google-search-to-python/4363882#4363882)), but it might be blocked (or worse, get wrong or empty answers) by Google, causing you program to stop working.

#### Pros and cons

If you just need to get some searches done for a project, use xGoogle. If your program needs to last longer, and you don't your searches to get blocked, spend the 15 minutes required to use their API.

Answer (score 2):

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```