# Finding the form box to fill using python

Tags: python, forms

My question is how do i locate the form box to fill and fill it with text automatically using python for example I want to go to google and automatially search for "dogs" using python how would i locate the search box and put that into code to fill. New to python would appreciate a break down of how to do this.

Comment: I think it won't be possible without using system api (which means loss of portability)

Comment: Is your question more about automating a web browser, or searching google with python?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do some google searches and get the results, [this other thread suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363861/returning-google-search-to-python) Python libraries which exist specifically for this purpose like [xGoogle](https://github.com/pkrumins/xgoogle), which would save you from having to write browser automation from scratch.

If you were just using Google as an example but want to do more extensive browser automation and run JavaScript and everything in a browser, you would want [a more robust automation tool](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp).

To get started as a beginner, you will want to figure out which Python browser/automation tools fit your needs best for what you want to accomplish, and then install the libraries and find some examples in the documentation - or ask a more specific question about the library on this site once you have tried to implement it!